# Session not working on third party sites when use on iFrame?

Tags: php, session, iframe, session-cookies

On my own site is working fine. even when I run iFrame on same host like `http://localhost/` its working but when I run other site(third party) like `http://www.example.com/` this type site not working. its happens only on Chrome and Edge browsers. my site working since 2015 but issue is raises past some days.

Comment: Third-party cookies often get blocked for privacy reasons, and browsers have become more strict with that in recent years.

Answer (score -1):

You can't use iframe for most 3rd party website because they are most likely intentionally having some sort of Frame Killer [read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller).

If you are the owner of the 3rd party site you need to give your website permission like this

`X-Frame-Options: allow-from https://your-website.com/`

Comment: I genuinely don't understand why is my answer being down voted, if i got anything wrong please let me know